# Flash a .hex to an ATtiny45 with Arduino

Tags: flash, attiny, sketch

I'm trying to upload a hex file to an ATtiny45 with an Arduino. I uploaded the Arduino ISP sketch to my board. I connected the ATtiny as shown below:

[image: Wiring diagram]

Then I go to CMD and type:

```
avrdude -c avrisp -p t45 -b 19200 -P COM6 -U flash:w:main.hex:i
```

And it gives me this error:

```
Please define PAGEL and BS2 signals for ATtiny45!
```

I double checked the connections and i tried to uplad a bootloader with Arduino IDE as written in this article: [Programming Hex-code on an Attiny85 with the Arduino](https://arduinodiy.wordpress.com/2012/09/11/programming-hex-code-on-an-attiny85-with-the-arduino). I can uplad sketches with ArduinoIDE with no error.

Answer (score 2):

Googling the error [gives this tutorial](http://highlowtech.org/?p=1229). Towards the bottom of the page they say

> You’ll probably get the following message, but don’t worry, the upload should have worked anyway:
>
> *avrdude: please define PAGEL and BS2 signals in the configuration file for part ATtiny85*

So it seems this can be ignored and the part has been programmed!

Comment: But the avrdude dont finish the programming, just write out the error